# how to stop one subview covering another

Tags: iphone, ios, addsubview

I have two subviews that load. One is a tabbar thats inside a viewcontroller which gets loaded fairly early on and the second is a view that appears when a tab bar item is pressed.

however when this subview is added it loads over the tabbar subview.. is there a way to bring to front or something along those lines?

Comment: got it.
insertSubview:belowSubview:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a whole plethora of methods to choose from...see the section **Managing the View Hierarchy** in the [UIView docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html)

Comment: yep sorry, I had looked in there but only at the top where all of the function/method normally hide but then after asking the question I went further down and found the solution....

Comment: should I delete the question or leave it here for other people?

Comment: Nobody is complaining so it probably won't hurt anything to leave it here.  If anything, this is a lesson to people to read the docs carefully before asking a question ^^.